# Will _forceinline virtual function from base class be __forceinlined in derived class without explicitly stating it?

Tags: c++, class, virtual, inline, derived

Suppose we have:

```
class Base
{
__forceinline virtual int A() {return 1;}
}


class Derived: public Base
{
    int A() 
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Function A in derived class is virtual without explicitly stating it. Will function A in derived class be also __forceinlined without explicitly stating it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, functions ***called virtually*** can't be inlined - the compiler needs to get to vtable pointer first to know which function to call. Not all functions marked `virtual` are called virtually - those can be inlined.

Then, `__forceinline` won't propagate to the derived class implementation - it's a non-standard compiler-specific keyword that has effect per function. So if you want to force inlining you have to apply the keyword again in the derived class function. Again it won't guarantee that all calls will be inlined.

Comment: nothing stops compiler to generate an out-of-line copy for same function if it needs to be inlined. so their will be 2 copies for function bodies -- one that needs to be called inlined and one that needs to be called virtually.

Comment: so virtual functions can be inlined, i mean nothing stops a programmer to make it inline. it will lead to code bloat but language does not pose restriction on doing it (although, again, it is a bad practise)

Comment: @Viren Shakya: True, but I say about inlining calls, not the function per se.

Comment: My objects are created statically, and I call them statically. In my case I need them to be inlined. Thank for answer, will write __forceinline in every function I need to be inlined.

Answer (score 2):

this should be documented in the compiler you are using, but to me, an "inlineness" -- whether forced or not, is something that is not part of contract for inheritance. so, no it should not.